# How do I place a m*n array within a M*N array?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I'm trying to stitch together 30px*30px images into a 3000px*3000px image. If there is a better way than what I'm describing could you please let me know.

I've created `BigArr = np.zeros((3000,3000))`. And I have my image arrays (which have dimensions 30px*30px). I want to place the first image so that it occupies all the space between `BigArr[0][0]` and `BigArr[29][29]`.

Is there an easy way to do this? Is there an even easier way to do what I'm trying to do overall?

Edit: The second image should occupy `[0][30]` -> `[59][29]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have exactly as many images as needed to completely fill your `BigArr` and your images can be stored in some list, you can create a nested list with the desired grid and use [`np.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) to generate such an image:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Image sizes (width x height)
img_w, img_h = (40, 30)
f_img_w, f_img_h = (200, 300)

# Number of rows / columns in final image
r = np.int32(f_img_h / img_h)
c = np.int32(f_img_w / img_w)

# Generate some images (stored in N-dimensional array)
imgs = np.ones((img_h, img_w, r * c), np.uint8) * 5 * (np.arange(r * c) + 1)

# Assumed starting point of procedure: All images stored in list
imgs_list = [imgs[:, :, i] for i in np.arange(imgs.shape[2])]

# Generate nested list with desired grid
imgs_nested_list = [[imgs_list[y * c + x] for x in np.arange(c)] for y in np.arange(r)]

# Generate desired image
big_arr = np.block(imgs_nested_list)

plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(big_arr, vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

The output from the example then would look like this:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc3
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: This worked for me except I created a python list of my uniform images then a M*N python array and used `np.block(arr)` on that array.